# How to select a percentage of sales records by vendor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I have a tables with vendors and orders. I want to return a percentage of order records per each vendor. Eg if I had 100 orders and the % is 10 I want to see random 10 orders records for that vendor. I'm using sql server mgmt studio.

Is it even possible to return all these results as one table? I have been attempting to use temp tables to pull some of the data but going through all vendors is not working.

```
Vendors
ID  % 
1   10
2   20
3   10
4   50

Order
ID  VID 
10   1
11   1
32   2
44   3
43   3
```

Comment: You can't just pull 10 random records.  You can pull the top 10, or 10 than fit a criteria.  But there is no randomizer that will just poke around the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your final query for each vendor would be:

```
SELECT TOP N * FROM [Order] WHERE VID = <yourVendorID> ORDER BY RAND()`
```

But the trouble is figuring out that `N` on the fly in a single query. We can get `N` using:

```
SELECT Round(COUNT(*)/Vendor.percentfield, 0) as [N], Vendor.ID as yourVendorID
FROM Order JOIN Vendors ON Order.VID = Vendor.ID
GROUP BY Vendor.percentField, Vendor.Id
```

Given that, I think your best bet would be to do this in a Stored Procedure so you can loop through the result set in that second query above and dynamically build the first query. You could make it into one big query by using `UNION` between each dynamically created SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I think this will get me on the right track.